# Highcharts, pass Data from json on Column Click

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to pass data from Series Point on Click
I have 2 examples first one is not working, that what i'd like to use.
But second one is working.

> [{"name":"Unknown","data":38.0,"DrillDown":{"Callback":"getActivityStatusReport","Arg":"0"},"selected":0},{"name":"Resolved","data":15.0,"DrillDown":{"Callback":"getActivityStatusReport","Arg":"-99"},"selected":0},{"name":"Open","data":255.0,"DrillDown":{"Callback":"getActivityStatusReport","Arg":"2"},"selected":0}]

Here's [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pyccki/EdwKj/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first example you are passing an array of series objects to options.series. In the second you are passing an array of point objects to the first series.  The "this" in the click callback is the point object getting clicked on.  In the first, your custom option is stored in the series object, and not that point.

What you need in the first is (fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/larsenmtl/EdwKj/11/)):

```
series: {
  cursor: 'pointer',
  point: {
    events: {
      click: function () {
        alert(this.series.options.DrillDown.Callback); // get the series for the point
       }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I actually found it right after i posted my Question, but couldn't answer own question within 8 hours, but then i forgot.
Here's update http://jsfiddle.net/pyccki/EdwKj/8/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's because of the latest Highcharts but the chosen answer doesn't work for me. For Highcharts v3.0.6 I got the right information from the following:

```
                series: {
                cursor: 'pointer',
                events: {
                    click: function (ev) {
                            console.log(ev.point.options.id);
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Hope the helps!

Comment: I've Updated Original jsfiddle, since HC changed reference to their Lib. Here's link and callBack is working with v3.0.10
http://jsfiddle.net/pyccki/EdwKj/23/